# evince 3.10.3 prints pdf file fields with shading as solid black

Tags: printing, pdf, evince

Evince suddenly started printing shaded boxes as solid black.  Probably upgraded in recent maintenance?
Evince 3.10.3, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  All Ubuntu updates applied (Mar.3, 2016). 
PDF print works OK with lpr, Gimp - but NOT xournal.
Tried on 2 different printers - same result:
   Brother HL2270 (Laser)
   Epson WF-3540  (Inkjet)
Some PDF other files print OK with evince - but not statements from my bank with "dot" shading.
Uninstalled/reinstalled evince - no change.